# Using git submodules with my own repo

Tags: git, vim, git-submodules, pathogen

I'm newbie in git, so question may be really stupid, sorry for that. I mean, I even found here on stackoverflow questions pretty close to mine, but still don't understand how to solve problem correctly.

I have github repo with my dotfiles, including for vim. I'm using **pathogen** with vim, so natural way to get plugins seams to be

```
git submodule add https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim.git vim/bundle/snipmate
...
git submodule init
git submodule update
git submodule foreach git submodule init
git submodule foreach git submodule update
```

wich I found somewhere. Last four commands I simply added to my setup script to run every time I clone this repo.

**The first problem** is `git status` always shows me

```
# modified:   vim/bundle/snipmate (untracked content)
# ...
```

in the `# Changed but not updated:` section and `git add vim/bundle/snipmate` doesn't help. It is pretty annoying.

**The second problem** is I obviously don't wand to keep **snipmate** snippets as default, I want to change them, and because of **pathogen** snippets are stored in **snipmate** folder, which is submodule, not my own repo. Of course, I could simply `clone` them there, or even create a fork of some of them, but is doesn't seem like a good solution:

- It messes up my own code with other's code can be found on github;
- I'm not really going to *modify* snipmate, I'm going to configure it;
- All that stuff makes complicated or even impossible to update thirty-part plugins.

Maybe someone could help with finding a "correct" answer?

Comment: forking is the only right and good solution for your second problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by reading [snipmate's doc](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/blob/master/doc/snipMate.txt#L180) which states that the default recommended location for your own snippets is (supposing your stuff is under `~/.vim`) `~/.vim/snippets/<filetype>.snippets`. Outside of the plugin's directory, outside of the submodule.

Yes Git submodules are cool but they are probably not the perfect solution for managing your Vim config.

Comment: Yeah, and when using pathogen it will be .vim/bundle/snipmate/snippets/. Of course, I still can create my own .vim/snippets/, but the default set will be loaded anyway.

Comment: The idea is to put your own snippets in their own location so that you can update snipmate without overwriting your snippets.

Comment: I don't know what is your problem. [Snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) doesn't ship with default snippets: you have to install them separately. If you don't like them and want to use your own snippets, just don't install the package and put your snippets in `~/.vim/snippets/`. I can't think of a simpler setup. If you are using the [old snipmate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim), like I do, there is absolutely no point of importing it as a submodule as the project has been totally dead for 2 years. The setting for the snippets dir is at L189 of `:h snipmate`.

Comment: Yes, I was using tho old one. Thank you for the hint. Anyway, the main problem is I many times heard it's a good point to store vim plugins as submodules with pathogen, but it looks to me it isn't. So the question is: am I doing something wrong? Or that's just really not very convenient?

Comment: Well, *I don't think that* Git submodules are a good fit for that purpose precisely because you'd end more often than not in a situation where it's more practical to just download a .zip and copy the files. The new snipmate makes sense as a submodule because all the snippets are externalized: you can `pull` a new version without overwriting your own snippets. But what if you also added the suggested snippets package, made changes to it and decide to `pull` the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I use snipmate and pathogen with vim. Pathogen makes using submodules possible (and much easier!)

My snipmate plugin is installed here:

```
.vim/bundle/snipmate
```

My snippets are installed here:

```
.vim/bundle/snipmate-snippets
```

An example snippet is here:

```
.vim/bundle/snipmate-snippets/snippets/c.snippets
```

I also have a work-specific repo with snippets. They're here:

```
.vim/bundle/work/snippets/cpp.snippets
```

So long as there's a snippets folder in your runtimepath (`:help rtp`), you're good. That's the magic of pathogen.

To setup my submodules I did:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate.git bundle/snipmate
git submodule add git://github.com/honza/snipmate-snippets.git bundle/snipmate-snippets
```

When I want to update my vim repo I do this:

```
git pull origin master
git submodule update --init
```

If I actually change the remote for a submodule (like if I forked snipmate on github and want to point my local repo at the new fork), I change .gitmodules and do:

```
git submodule sync
```

By using submodules, it will make it easier to update `git submodule git pull origin` and easier to modify and push updates back to the maintainer.